# How to make detailed screen that has audio in it after user clicked on the listview item

Tags: android, flutter, listview, audio, just-audio

How do I make detail screen that has an audio in each of them. Do i have to declare for each audio player for each listview item? May anyone can give me insights to make it simpler as possible? Btw, i use just_audio plugin. Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me :)

[image: This is the image of the listview]

[image: This is the image of the detail screen]

//the declaration

```
late AudioPlayer player;
late AudioPlayer player2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    player = AudioPlayer();
    player2 = AudioPlayer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    player.dispose();
    player2.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

//audio player button that I intended to put in detail screen for each listview item

```
FlatButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  try {
                    await player.setAsset("assets/audio/mim dengung.mp3");
                    player.play();
                  } on PlayerException catch (e) {
                    print("Error code: ${e.code}");
                    print("Error message: ${e.message}");
                  } on PlayerInterruptedException catch (e) {
                    print("Connection aborted: ${e.message}");
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
                },
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                shape: StadiumBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white54, width: 2)),
                child: Container(
                  width: 80,
                  height: 50,
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 3, horizontal: 10),
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    shape: StadiumBorder(),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.volume_up_outlined),
                      Text(
                        " م ",
                        style:
                            TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 25),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

this is the listview item in which it will display detail screen (code below) if user click on any listview item

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

import '../../constants.dart';
import 'detail_screen.dart';
import 'model.dart';

class Basic extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<Basic> {
  List<Item> _itemList = [
    Item(
        title: "Hamzah Wasal",
        longText:
            "Hamzah Wasal adalah hamzah zaidah (tambahan) yang berada pada awal. Ia harus diucapkan jika berada di awal kalimah dan tidak diucapkan jika disambung dengan ayat sebelumnya.\n\nHamzah Wasal dibaca Dhommah(baris depan) apabila huruf ketiga adalah Dhommah. Jika huruf ketiga adalah Fathah (baris atas) atau Kasrah (baris bawah), ia perlu dibaca dengan Kasrah.",
        image: "assets/images/hamzah_wasal.jpg"),
    Item(
        title: "Ghunnah",
        longText:
            "Dari segi bahasa ia bermaksud suara yang keluar dari pangkal rongga hidung.\n\nDari segi istilah ia bermaksud suara yang indah dan teratur pada huruf nun(termasukk tanwin) dan mim.\n\nDalam keadaan normal, makhraj mim adalah dua bibir bertemu dan makhraj nun adalah hujung lidah bertemu lelangit mulut. Tetapi dalam keadaan ghunnah, makhraj mim dan nun bercampur dengan khaisyum (baca lebih lanjut dalam bahagian makhraj).",
        image: "assets/images/hamzah_wasal.jpg"),
    Item(
        title: "Sukun",
        longText:
            "Terdapat 2 jenis sukun (mati) di dalam Al Quran. Sukun yg pertama dinamakan Sukun Asli manakala yg kedua adalah Sukun yg mendatang.\n\nSukun Asli adalah huruf yg bertanda sukun. Sukun itu dibaca sama ada ketika waqaf (berhenti) mahupun ketika wasal (sambung). Dinamakan Asli kerana ia tidak berubah dan merupakan asal kepada huruf tersebut bertanda sukun.\n\nContoh hukum adalah pada Mad Lazim Kalimi.\n\nSukun mendatang pula atau disebut ‘aridhah adalah sukun yg terhasil daripada huruf yg bertanda (baris, sabdu atau tanwin). Disebut sukun mendatang adalah disebabkan berlaku sesuatu pada huruf berbaris tersebut iaitu waqaf (berhenti). Ia menjadi sukun apabila waqaf tetapi kembali kepada bacaan asalnya berbaris apabila wasal (sambung).\n\nContohnya adalah pada hukum Mad Aridh Lissukun.",
        image: "assets/images/hamzah_wasal.jpg"),
    Item(
        title: "Mad Ta’zhim",
        longText:
            "Mad Ta’zhim ialah mad pada perkataan لآ bererti “tidak” ketika pertemuannya dengan perkataan yang terdapat pada kalimah tauhid (إله).\n\n Bagi mereka yang membaca mad jaiz munfasil dengan kadar 2/4/6 harakat, apabila bertemu perkataan (إله) di dalam kalimah tauhid, ia dibaca 6 harakat.",
        image: "assets/images/mad silah qasirah.jpg"),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: primaryColor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Asas"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _itemList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            DetailScreen(item: _itemList[index])),
                  );
                },
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(18),
                    child: Text(
                      _itemList[index].title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 19,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ));
          },
        )));
  }
}
```

this is the detailed screen that will appear after user click on any listview item

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../constants.dart';
import 'model.dart';

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Item item;
  const DetailScreen({Key? key, required this.item}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Column(children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: Text(
                  item.title,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: Text(
                  item.longText,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.5),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 100, child: Image.asset(item.image)),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

//This is the error I got after adding the audio player logic. Idk where to declare the audio player in the DetailScreen class

[image: This is the error I got after adding the audio player logic.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already passing `title`, `longText` and `image` to your `DetailScreen` inside an `Item`. So you can just add the `audio` to `Item` as well and have access to that inside your `DetailScreen`. Then you can move the audio player logic to your `DetailScreen` and just use one audio player which would play the audio based on `item.audio`.

**UPDATE**

`DetailScreen` code:

```
class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Item item;
  const DetailScreen({Key? key, required this.item}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DetailScreen> createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
  final _player = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _init();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    widget.item.title,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    widget.item.longText,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.5),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  child: Image.asset(widget.item.image),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: _player.play,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                  shape: StadiumBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white54, width: 2)),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 50,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 3, horizontal: 10),
                    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      shape: StadiumBorder(),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(Icons.volume_up_outlined),
                        Text(
                          " م ",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 25),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _init() async {
    _player.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {}, onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      print('A stream error occurred: $e');
    });
    try {
      await _player.setAsset("assets/audio/mim dengung.mp3");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error loading audio source: $e");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already added that but apparently there are some errors that idk how to solve. Could you please enlighten me how to solve that part? Btw I have already edited which part I got errors above

Comment: @AidaQilah You're using `initState` and `dispose` inside a `StatelessWidget`, but these are only available in a `StatefulWidget`. Check the documentation for `StatefulWidgets`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html

Comment: @AidaQilah Also I use Android Studio so I'm not sure what the shortcut is in VSCode, but if you put your cursor on `DetailScreen` a lightbulb shows and when you click on that there will be an option to convert to `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: I tried use Stateful too but there are errors. Btw, Thank you for replying Ramin :)

Comment: @AidaQilah Did you use VSCode for converting to stateful or did you change the extends from `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget` manually? If you did it manually it's not enough to just rename it like this. If you did it using VSCode what are the new errors?

Comment: Hi, Ramin. I am so sorry for the late reply. This is what I done to prevent the error but these definitely wrong since it does not declare audio player to invoke it (bcs if added audio player, there will be an error)

class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Item item;
  const DetailScreen({Key? key, required this.item}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DetailScreenState createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

Comment: @AidaQilah You can just declare the player inside `_DetailScreenState` by using `final _player = AudioPlayer()`. I've updated my answer to show the full code for `DetailScreen`.

Comment: It's workinggg! Thank you Ramin. I've been searching for another solution since yesterday. Appreciate it :)